# An example of a commutative infinitely generated algebra having zero divisors

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a commutative $k$-algebra, where $k$ is a field of characteristic zero.

> Could one please give an example of such $R$ which is also:
>
> **(i)** Not affine (= infinitely generated as a $k$-algebra).
>
> and
>
> **(ii)** Not an integral domain (= has zero divisors).

My first thought was $k[x_1,x_2,\ldots]$, the polynomial ring over $k$ in infinitely many variables, but unfortunately, it satisfies condition **(i)** only. It is not difficult to see that it is an integral domain: If $fg=0$ for some $f,g \in k[x_1,x_2,\ldots]$, then there exists $M \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $f,g \in k[x_1,\ldots,x_M]$, so if we think of $fg=0$ in $k[x_1,\ldots,x_M]$, we get that $f=0$ or $g=0$, and we are done.

Thank you very much!

Comment: This post is missing your thoughts on the problem: what have you tried? This should be relatively straightforwards.

Comment: Truly, I thought to add a remark which says that $k[x_i]_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ is not an example, since it (ii) is not satisfied.

Comment: Can you think of something that satisfies the first? Can you think of something that satisfies the second? How can you put these two things together to get something that works?

Comment: @user3482749, thank you. After I have seen the answer, I have also figured out the ideas of your comment.

Comment: In regards to your edited generalization, it is not within the community standards to alter the question so dramatically after you've accepted an answer. You should ask your generalization as a new question.

Comment: I apologize, I did not know this. Ok, I will fix this soon. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For instance, $k[X_n\,:\, n\in\Bbb N]/(X_n^2\,:\, n\in\Bbb N)$: the ring of polynomials in infinitely many variables quotiented by the ideal generated by the square of the variables.

Comment: Thank you. (I have just edited my question to a slightly less trivial question).