# Characterizing commutative infinitely generated algebras having zero divisors

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a commutative $k$-algebra, where $k$ is a field of characteristic zero. Assume that $R$ satisfies the following two conditions:

**(i)** $R$ is not affine (= $R$ is infinitely generated as a $k$-algebra).

**(ii)** $R$ is not an integral domain (= $R$ has zero divisors).

After receiving an easy answer to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3008571/an-example-of-a-commutative-infinitely-generated-algebra-having-zero-divisors?noredirect=1#comment6205088_3008571) question, I would like to generalize it to the following question:

> Is it possible to characterize all such $R$'s?

If I am not wrong, all such $R$'s are of the following form:
$\frac{k[x_i]_{i \in \mathbb{N}}}{I}$, for an appropriate ideal $I$, for example $I=(x_{17}^2)$.
How to find all such $I$'s?

> Is it true that a general such $I$ is an ideal generated by at least one *reducible* polynomial? (clearly, if $h=h_1h_2 \in I$, then $\bar{h_1}\bar{h_2}=\bar{0}$).

Thank you very much!

**Edit:** Perhaps the power series ring in infinitely many variables (which is an integral domain) quotiented by an appropriate ideal shows that I was wrong, and not all such $R$'s are quotients of polynomial rings in infinitely many variables.

Comment: Well in your question you only ask for infinitely generated, but all your $R$'s are countably generated, so any uncountably generated ring lies outside the class you suggest.

Comment: Thanks, you are right. I actually meant to ask about $\frac{k[x_i]_{i \in A}}{I}$, for an arbitrary set $A$, countably generated or not.

Comment: @AlexJBest, if my question still interests you, please see my edit (in which I claim that there exist such $R$'s of another form as well).

Comment: Every commutative ring whatsoever is a quotient of a polynomial ring in enough variables (for example, it suffices to take one variable for each element of the ring). But asking for a classification is totally hopeless.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, thank you.